# Update view with django-formtools

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-formwizard, django-formtools, updateview

I implemented django-formtools SessionWizardView with a navbar, so I can jump between steps if I want to update existing instances.

My problem is, if I want to edit an instance I have to submit all forms, so they are valid and render_done is called.